# Tempo logado no sistema com Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia. Gostaria de saber se o Láravel 4.2 tem alguma funcionalidade que me diga o tempo em que o usuário ficou logado no sistema? Por exemplo, quando o usuário se deslogar, eu salvo no banco esse tempo. Quando o usuário se logar de novo, e depois se deslogar, eu somo o tempo que ele ficou no primeiro acesso com esse último, ou seja, preciso saber o tempo total que o usuário ficou logado no sistema.

Comment: Daniel, então, não tem nada pronto nesse sentido, tem que ser criado via programação.

Comment: Entendi, bom, vou procurar algo para ver se consigo adaptar

Comment: Daniel não é dificil é só uma tabela e um código para gravar nela, ao dar login e logout no usuário.

Comment: Então, eu preciso criar 2 campos? Um para login e outro para logout?

Comment: Vai depender da implementação em seu todo, vai ter que ter o campo UserId, Entrada e Saída, eu vejo assim logo de cara, claro pode ser adicionado outros campos.

Comment: Então, eu achei esse script aqui:
round((strtotime($usuario->hora_entrada) - strtotime($hora_saida))/3600, 1); só que sempre me retorna -0

Comment: [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/181065/edit) a sua questão e coloque o seu progresso até o momento, com os problema encontrada agora. Mas, coloque tudo que fez as mudanças na tabela e o que deseja, o que espera do seu código que ainda não está acontecendo ...